# How to pass a jinja variable into flask using url_for

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a form in HTML that looks like this:

```
             <form action="{{ url_for('home_blueprint.tabledata', tablename = col )}}" method="post">

                <select name="tables" placeholder="Table" id="tables" size=3>
                      {% for col in column_names %}
                      <option value = "{{ col }}">{{ col }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                </select>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Basically, the form above displays a drop-down list of items {{ col }}. I want that a selected and submitted item from the list above (for example: 'tablename' ) appears in my URL like [www.example.com/tabledata/tablename](http://www.example.com/tabledata/tablename)

My flask code is here:

```
     @blueprint.route('/tabledata/<tablename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
     @login_required

     def tabledata(tablename):

         return render_template('index.html', tablename=tablename)
```

In other words, I want to pass a variable from this form to flask using url_for.

How I do that? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/tutorial/templates/

Comment: @RonnyAtoche did my answer help you? If yes, please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. I'll go with the most basic one (at least for me).

You just need to tweak your function so if someone submits a `GET` request, he/she gets the dropdown list, and if the user submits a `POST` request, fetch the POST data and redirect him/her to another url, the dynamic one.

So your flask code becomes:

```
@blueprint.route('/tabledata/<tablename>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def tablename(tablename):
    return "Hi"

@blueprint.route('/tabledata')
@login_required
def tabledata():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', column_names=['abc', 'def', 'ghi']) # Column names were added by me, ignore it
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.get("tables")
        return redirect(url_for('tablename', tablename=data))
```

And just a little change to the form action:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('home_blueprint.tabledata')}}" method="POST">

        <select name="tables" placeholder="Table" id="tables" size=3>
              {% for col in column_names %}
                <option class="column" value="{{ col }}">{{ col }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
        </select>
    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now if you click on an option, say 'abc', from the dropdown, and submit it, you will be taken to the url `www.example.com/tabledata/abc` .